# Serverless Framework and how to enable AWS State Machine to be called by an S3 event rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch, serverless-framework, aws-step-functions

As per the documentation of the Serverless Framework plugin, [See examples here](https://github.com/serverless-operations/serverless-step-functions#cloudwatch-alarms) we are able to enable our Statemachine to be called by an EC2 event rule.

(From above link )

```yaml
stepFunctions:
  stateMachines:
    first:
      events:
        - cloudwatchEvent:
            event:
              source:
                - "aws.ec2"
              detail-type:
                - "EC2 Instance State-change Notification"
              detail:
                state:
                  - pending
      definition:
        ...
```

I want my State Machine to be called from an S3 event rule.

However, as per [AWS CloudWatch Even Types documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/EventTypes.html), it does not look like we are able to use the S3 event rule as it does not appear in AWS CloudWatch Even Types documentation link

So does it means I can not use this plug-in to call my State machine based on an S3 event rule, like for example a new object uploaded to S3 ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the types of S3 events you are trying to trigger from.

The link you provided shows that you [can use CloudTrail events to trigger CloudWatch event rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-CloudTrail-Rule.html).  This would allow you to trigger on events such as creating/removing buckets.

If you want to trigger off of things like objects being added/deleted from a bucket, then you will not be able to do it without writing some additional resources.  You can [create S3 events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html) to trigger SQS, SNS or [a Lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html).  My suggestion would be to implement a lambda function that accepts an S3 event and kicks off your state machine as desired.  Then create an S3 event to trigger your lambda when the desired object event occurs.

Comment: Just some more links:

 - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-cloudwatch-events-s3.html

 - There is an architecture of the solution at the bottom of the page.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/constructs/aws-s3-step-function.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think it is only possible that way, through cloud watch. That is also explained here in this [AWS Tutorail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-cloudwatch-events-s3.html). As per the plugin documentation, there is only 3 source of events:  CloudWtach, API Gateway, scheduled events.

Comment: On the other hand, the AWS documentation lists all the AWS services that could emit events that could be detected by CloudWatch [services in the following list emit events that can be detected by CloudWatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/EventTypes.html#cloudwatch-event-type). Missing is S3 so definitely looks like we will need

Comment: That brings me back to my question. How to do it with Serverless Framework?